# Is it possible to specify HTTP headers in the URL?

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, url, browser

I've got a (Spring) handler that I'd like users to be able to bookmark. As it's coded now, they get different formats (CSV, JSON) back based on the Accept header.

Would there be any way for users to specify the URL so that they can say what header they want? Or am I going to have to give URL-level parameter for the different formats?

Comment: you have to give the query parameter so that you add the header accordingly . you cannot have header as part of url

Answer (score 1):

> Would there be any way for users to specify the URL so that they can say what header they want? 
>   no there is no way to do that magically.
>
> Or am I going to have to give URL-level parameter for the different formats? Yes this is valid

This is quoted from xml.com:

1. Server-driven negotiation. The service provider determines the right representation from prior knowledge of its clients or uses the information provided in HTTP headers like Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, and User-Agent. The drawback of this approach is that the server may not have the best knowledge about what a client really wants.
2. Client-driven negotiation. A client initiates a request to a server. The server returns a list of available of representations. The client then selects the representation it wants and sends a second request to the server. The drawback is that a client needs to send two requests.
3. Proxy-driven negotiation. A client initiates a request to a server through a proxy. The proxy passes the request to the server and obtains a list of representations. The proxy selects one representation according to preferences set by the client and returns the representation back to the client.
4. URI-specified representation. A client specifies the representation it wants in the URI query string.